# Solr Nextcursor mark returning error Unable to parse 'cursorMark' after totem

Tags: java, json, rest, solr

On my code I am trying to search for page and getting result I have included cursor mark as `*` when I get the return next cursor mark as `"AoE/SkhJVkVfRFNDNjAwNDlfVklTVEFfVklTVEFQX1RaX0RCOi8vSGl2ZSBNZXRhc3RvcmUvZHNjNjAwNDlfdmlzdGFfdmlzdGFwX3R6X2RiL2Fucl9sb2dvbl9sb2cvbG9nX3RpbWVzdGFtcA==` where it's throwing error:

> Unable to parse 'cursorMark' after totem: value must either be '*' or the 'nextCursorMark' returned by a previous search

I need to encode the `nextCursorMark` here is my code below:

```
do {
    String response = RestClient.doGet(url, userName, password, offSetTemp, pageSize, cursorMark);
    System.out.println("res:----"+response);
    jsonObject = ProfileDataExportUtil.getJson(response);
    JsonArray profilingInfo = null;
    if (jsonObject.has("items")) {
        profilingInfo = jsonObject.get("items").getAsJsonArray();
    }
    if (profilingInfo == null) continue;
    moreResultsExists = profilingInfo.size() >= 1;
    ProfileDataExporter.writeProfileInformation(bWriter, profilingInfo);
    if (!jsonObject.has("nextCursorMark")) continue;
    cursorMark = jsonObject.get("nextCursorMark").toString();
} while (moreResultsExists);
```

I have tried using `tostring` which throws an error.

My URL is encoded and when I use

```
cursorMark = jsonObject.get("nextCursorMark").getAsString();
```

I get `"string out of bound exception"` error.

Can anyone tell me how encode the `nextCursorMark`?

Comment: Hi, how you solve the issue ? I am also facing similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue. It was due to nextCursor  String encoding. You should encode this string also before appending in the final URL. A sample example is given below

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
...
cursorMark = quote_plus(response['nextCursorMark'])
...
```